# Visits to web page is counted multitple times php

Tags: php, if-statement, logfile

So there is the problem:

I've made some php code to register page views (with a lot of help from stack overflow). I specifically want to avoid using cookies for this. Also I would prefer not to use an SQL DB if it is possible a well working solution without it.

To deal with browser behaviour like prefetching and the like, I am trying to filter out the extra page views with an if, elseif, else function.

The problem in practice is that the sometimes pageviews are either written twice to the log file or there is a timing issue with the if-statement and the rest of the code.

Here is the code I have:

```
<?php

/*set variables  for log file */
$useragnt = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; //get  user agent
$ipaddrs = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //get ipaddress 
$filenameLog = "besog/" . date("Y-m-d") . "LOG.txt"; 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
$infoToLog = $ipaddrs .  "\t" . $useragnt . "\t" . date('H:i:s') . "\n";
$file_arr = file($filenameLog);
$last_row = $file_arr[count($file_arr) - 1];
$arr = explode( "\t", $last_row);
$tidForSidsteLogLinje = strtotime($arr[2]);
$tidNu = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));

//write ip, useragent and time of page view to log file logfil, but only if the same visitor has not viewed the page within the last 10 seconds
if ($arr[0] == $ipaddrs and $arr[1] == $useragnt and $tidNu - $tidForSidsteLogLinje > 10){
    //write ip and user agent to textfile
    $file = fopen($filenameLog,  "a+");
    fwrite($file, $infoToLog); 
    fclose($file);

}
elseif ($arr[0] == $ipaddrs and $arr[1] == $useragnt and $tidNu - $tidForSidsteLogLinje < 10){
    die;
}
else {                      
    //Write ip and user agent to textfile
    $file = fopen($filenameLog,  "a+");
    fwrite($file, $infoToLog); 
    fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

Here are examples of the duplicate entries in the log (I have masked some of the ipaddresses):

```
xxx.x.95.240    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko    12:52:33 
xx.xxx.229.91   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36   12:52:45 
xx.xxx.229.91   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36   12:52:45 
xxx.xx.154.83   ServiceTester/4.4.64.1514   12:53:03 
xxx.xx.91.126   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5   12:53:05 
xx.xxx.35.3 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36  12:53:09 
xxx.xxx.130.34  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko    12:53:56 
xxx.xxx.130.34  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko    12:53:56 
xx.xxx.211.101  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36  12:54:11 
x.xxx.54.4  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/601.6.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.1 Safari/601.6.17  12:54:33
```

If my if-statements were working as intended, it should be possible to see duplicate lines in the entries like in the above.

How do I improve the code to eliminate these duplicate entries?

And help or suggestions is much appreciated!

Comment: Before inserting into the file, once check if the IP already exists in the log. If it exists already don't insert, else insert into file.

Comment: @phpfresher Am I not checking excatly this in the if-statement:
`if ($arr[0] == $ipaddrs and $arr[1] == $useragnt and $tidNu - $tidForSidsteLogLinje > 10)` 
?

Answer (score 0):

We use a Complex Website Visitor Track / log System in our system. 
I would recomend that you store this Values in a Database and set the IP address field as Unique.

You can set an CookieID like

```
Cookie::set('__id', time());
```

and go like

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['__id'])){

        //With mysql you go like
        $db->Execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO VisitorTable(hash, ip,..) 
       VALUES($_COOKIE['__id'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] )" // the HTTP_USER_AGENT refferer all kind of information that you wannt to store
        }
```

This way the Visitor Only exist once in your list. See [insert ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) for more.

Now you can eazy make an other function to save the pages the user visits .
In a script that gets everytime executet you go like:

```
$db->Execute("INSERT INTO VisitorActivity (visitorID,page....) VALUES ($_COOKIE['__id'],$_Server['..'])" );
```

Comment: just an cleaner Solutions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that my question needs to be updated since I specifically want to avoid the use of cookies.